# Keras, gradients w.r.t.('categorical_crossentropy') loss and weights vanish if probs for actual right class are small (<e-07)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gradient

I need the gradient of an input-target combination regarding the loss (categorical_crossentropy) of a trained model. For most examples the gradients look good, but the further the network is trained, the more input-target combinations occur for which all gradients are zero. Why is that, since this happens when the probabilities are absolutely unlike the target?

I define the network as follows:

```py
X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = get_data(dataset) #load Mnist data

layers = [
            Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='valid', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),  # 0
            Activation('relu'),  # 1
            BatchNormalization(),  # 2
            Conv2D(64, (3, 3)),  # 3
            Activation('relu'),  # 4
            BatchNormalization(),  # 5
            MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),  # 6
            Dropout(0.5),  # 7
            Flatten(),  # 8
            Dense(128),  # 9
            Activation('relu'),  # 10
            BatchNormalization(),  # 11
            Dropout(0.5),  # 12
            Dense(10),  # 13
            Activation('softmax'), #14
        ]

for layer in layers:
    model.add(layer)

model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',#'mean_squared_error',#
    optimizer='adadelta',
    metrics=['accuracy']
    )
```

Next I write a function that calculates the gradients (http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2017/10/debugging-keras-networks.html). For debugging, I plot the predictions and the gradients of the last layer

```py
def get_weight_grad(model, X_train, Y_train):
    weights = model.trainable_weights  # weight tensors
    gradients = model.optimizer.get_gradients(model.total_loss, weights)
    input_tensors = [model.inputs[0],  # input data
                     model.sample_weights[0],  # how much to weight sample
                     model.targets[0],  # labels
                     K.learning_phase(),  # train or test mode
                     ]
    get_gradients = K.function(inputs=input_tensors, outputs=gradients)
    for i in range(len(X_train)):
        x = np.expand_dims(X_train[i], axis=0)
        y = np.expand_dims(Y_train[i], axis=0)
        print()
        print('y',y)

        inputs = [x, [1], y, 0]
        grads = get_gradients(inputs)
        print('grads_last', grads[-1])
        preds = model.predict_proba(x, verbose=0, batch_size=1)
        print('preds', preds)
```

Now I train epoch by epoch. Before each epoch I call the function get_weight_grads to calculate the gradients for every possible label.

```py
for epoche in range(10):
    print('epoch', epoche )
    for i in range(10):
        y = np.zeros(10)
        y[i] = 1 # create all possible target values
        x = np.expand_dims(X_train[10], axis=0)
        y = np.expand_dims(y, axis = 0 )
        get_weight_grad(model, x,  y)

    model.fit_generator(
        datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
        steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) / batch_size,
        epochs=1,
        verbose=1,
        validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

The gradients before the first training epoch look as expected, unequal to zero. But after a view training epochs some gradients vanish to zero. Here i show the print after epoch 6.

```
y [[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
grads_last [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]  ########### The problem is e.g. HERE
preds [[2.3776792e-10 1.5075612e-07 1.1485033e-05 9.9945003e-01 1.4578478e-07
  5.3489784e-04 1.3318672e-08 1.8227190e-06 1.4657907e-06 3.3539639e-08]]

y [[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
grads_last [ 2.3776789e-10 -9.9999982e-01  1.1485031e-05  9.9944991e-01
  1.4578477e-07  5.3489779e-04  1.3318671e-08  1.8227188e-06
  1.4657904e-06  3.3539635e-08]
preds [[2.3776792e-10 1.5075612e-07 1.1485033e-05 9.9945003e-01 1.4578478e-07
  5.3489784e-04 1.3318672e-08 1.8227190e-06 1.4657907e-06 3.3539639e-08]]

y [[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
grads_last [ 2.3776792e-10  1.5075612e-07 -9.9998862e-01  9.9945003e-01
  1.4578478e-07  5.3489784e-04  1.3318672e-08  1.8227190e-06
  1.4657907e-06  3.3539639e-08]
preds [[2.3776792e-10 1.5075612e-07 1.1485033e-05 9.9945003e-01 1.4578478e-07
  5.3489784e-04 1.3318672e-08 1.8227190e-06 1.4657907e-06 3.3539639e-08]]

y [[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
grads_last [ 2.37767889e-10  1.50756108e-07  1.14850318e-05 -5.50014956e-04
  1.45784767e-07  5.34897787e-04  1.33186715e-08  1.82271890e-06
  1.46579055e-06  3.35396351e-08]
preds [[2.3776792e-10 1.5075612e-07 1.1485033e-05 9.9945003e-01 1.4578478e-07
  5.3489784e-04 1.3318672e-08 1.8227190e-06 1.4657907e-06 3.3539639e-08]]

y [[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
grads_last [ 2.3776786e-10  1.5075609e-07  1.1485031e-05  9.9944985e-01
 -9.9999976e-01  5.3489773e-04  1.3318670e-08  1.8227187e-06
  1.4657904e-06  3.3539632e-08]
preds [[2.3776792e-10 1.5075612e-07 1.1485033e-05 9.9945003e-01 1.4578478e-07
  5.3489784e-04 1.3318672e-08 1.8227190e-06 1.4657907e-06 3.3539639e-08]]

y [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
grads_last [ 2.37767889e-10  1.50756108e-07  1.14850318e-05  9.99449968e-01
  1.45784767e-07 -9.99465108e-01  1.33186715e-08  1.82271890e-06
  1.46579055e-06  3.35396351e-08]
preds [[2.3776792e-10 1.5075612e-07 1.1485033e-05 9.9945003e-01 1.4578478e-07
  5.3489784e-04 1.3318672e-08 1.8227190e-06 1.4657907e-06 3.3539639e-08]]

y [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]]
grads_last [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
preds [[2.3776792e-10 1.5075612e-07 1.1485033e-05 9.9945003e-01 1.4578478e-07
  5.3489784e-04 1.3318672e-08 1.8227190e-06 1.4657907e-06 3.3539639e-08]]

y [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
grads_last [ 2.37767889e-10  1.50756108e-07  1.14850318e-05  9.99449968e-01
  1.45784767e-07  5.34897787e-04  1.33186715e-08 -9.99998212e-01
  1.46579055e-06  3.35396351e-08]
preds [[2.3776792e-10 1.5075612e-07 1.1485033e-05 9.9945003e-01 1.4578478e-07
  5.3489784e-04 1.3318672e-08 1.8227190e-06 1.4657907e-06 3.3539639e-08]]

y [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]
grads_last [ 2.37767889e-10  1.50756108e-07  1.14850318e-05  9.99449968e-01
  1.45784767e-07  5.34897787e-04  1.33186715e-08  1.82271890e-06
 -9.99998569e-01  3.35396351e-08]
preds [[2.3776792e-10 1.5075612e-07 1.1485033e-05 9.9945003e-01 1.4578478e-07
  5.3489784e-04 1.3318672e-08 1.8227190e-06 1.4657907e-06 3.3539639e-08]]

y [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
grads_last [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
preds [[2.3776792e-10 1.5075612e-07 1.1485033e-05 9.9945003e-01 1.4578478e-07
  5.3489784e-04 1.3318672e-08 1.8227190e-06 1.4657907e-06 3.3539639e-08]]
```

e.g. for the last example output combination the label, since the predictions are completely different from the values of target y, the gradients should be high and not zero. What is wrong here?
The only connection I can make, is that for the zero gradient examples, the probability value for which the target one hot vector has its one, is quite small (